# Combine multiple lines of C# code for brevity or separate for clarity

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to c# and trying to learn best practices.  I've been faced with many situations over the last week in which I need to make a choice between longer+simpler code, or shorter code that combines several actions into a single statement.  What are some standards you veteran coders use when trying to write clear, concise code?  Here is an example of code I'm writing with two options.  Which is preferable?

A)

```
        if (ncPointType.StartsWith("A"))//analog points
        {
            string[] precisionString = Regex.Split(unitsParam.Last(), ", ");
            precision = int.Parse(precisionString[1]);
        }
        else
            precision = null;
```

B)

```
        if (ncPointType.StartsWith("A"))//analog points
            precision = int.Parse(Regex.Split(unitsParam.Last(), ", ")[1]);
        else
            precision = null;
```

Comment: This question is better for Programmers' Stack Exchange. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd say B, but only because it's consistent in the use of `{ }` (or rather, the not-use). Apart from that making code readable is almost always more important than making code concise.

Comment: I'd also suggest `int.TryParse` and checking the result in case the value from the `Split` is not an integer.  This will allow you to handle the error gracefully in the code rather than having an exception thrown (and possibly bringing the application down).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right or wrong. This is opinion based really.

However, remember that whether you add braces, add comments, add whitespace or whatever, it doesn't affect the performance or the size of the final assembly because the compiler optimizes it very well. So, why not go with the more verbose so that other programmers can follow it easier?

Comment: +1 for *so that other programmers can follow it easier*

Comment: +1 for the above and the simple fact that it makes it easier for you if you come back to the code 6 months later and don't remember what you did exactly (or why).  Short code is always neat looking and a fun challenge, but the maintainability and readability are more important in the long run (IMO).

Comment: @Tim you should leave out the *(IMO)* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically subject to the coding standard you choose. There is no right or wrong, just personal preference.

Agree as a team what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to debug option A, but option B is more concise while still being readable. You could make it even more concise with a ternary operator:

```
precision = ncPointType.StartsWith("A") ? int.Parse(Regex.Split(unitsParam.Last(), ", ")[1]) : null;
```

Although it's far more readable this way (and still works the same way!):

```
precision = ncPointType.StartsWith("A") ? 
                int.Parse(Regex.Split(unitsParam.Last(), ", ")[1]) : 
                null;
```

It's best to stick with the standards used in your project.  ***Readability*** is far more important for ***maintainability*** than having less lines of code.  In both options, the ***efficiency*** is the same, so you don't need to worry about speed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

But even better is:

```
precision = ncPointType.StartsWith("A")? 
                 int.Parse(Regex.Split(unitsParam.Last(), ", ")):
                 null;
```

This expresses the function beiong executed (*set the precision*),
 and the conditions that control how it is set, in even less code,
  -  without creating unnecessary temporary variables to hold a temporary result that is not used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me both A and B are bad practice. You should always use braces regardless of whether or not it is one line or multiple lines. This helps to prevent bugs in the future when people add additional lines of code to your if or else blocks and don't notice that the braces are missing.

Sometimes having "more" code, like using temporary variables, etc., will make your code easier to debug as you can hover over symbols. It's all about balance, and this comes with experience. Remember that you may not be the only one working on your code, so clarity above all.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it comes down to your choice because it has nothing to do with performance, but I would also note that you cannot instantiate or define variables if you omit the curly braces:

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 0)
    int b = 3;
```

Is not valid, whereas:

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 0)
{
    int b = 3;
}
```

Is valid.

Comment: Should anyone care, the first example gives `error CS1023: An embedded statement may not be a declaration or labeled statement`

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else here points out, there are no hard and fast "rules" per se, but there should probably be braces around both block of code; both A and B have characteristics similar to the [Apple goto bug](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) because the introduce potential ambiguity.

Consider:

```
void Main()
{
    int x=1;
    if (x==1)
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    else if (x==2)
        Console.WriteLine("NOT 1");
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

will produce

```
1
OK
```

To someone scanning the code, especially if it's surrounded by other, innocuous looking code, this could easily be misread as "only print "OK" if `x==2`). Obviously some people will spot it, some won't, but why introduce the danger for the want of a brace of braces :)